# Assistance creating calculated columns with Pandas Groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas Dataframe, called relevant_URT_data, that looks like this:

test MRN Number ResCat
12 AP Disbursements Payment Details URT INC3778700 0
33 AP Disbursements Payment Details NaN INC3783080 0
72 AP Disbursements Payment Details URT INC3782671 0
150 AP Quality Assurance Payment Status URT INC3778770 0
178 PR HBS Inquiry NaN INC3776742 1
192 AP Quality Assurance Payment Status NaN INC3778547 0
315 AP Quality Assurance Payment Status URT INC3780548 0
328 PR Accounting W-2 Form URT INC3782016 0
355 AP General Submit Invoice for Payment URT INC3781884 0
374 AP General Inquiry NaN INC3775944 0

I use the following code to group the data by test - please see image below.

```
test_breakdown = relevant_URT_data[["test","MRN","Number"]] \
        .groupby("test") \
        .agg({'MRN':'count', 'Number':'size'}) \
        .rename(columns={'MRN':'URT Use Count','Number':'Number'})
```

test URT Use Count Number 
AP Connexxus Access Request 9 9 
AP Disbursements Payment Details 28 35 
AP General Inquiry 1 7 
AP General Submit Invoice for Payment 25 27 
AP General WebNow/Invoice Copies 0 4 
AP MyExpense Access Request 3 3 
AP MyExpense Grant Delegated Access 0 1 
AP MyExpense Inquiry 2 8 
AP Quality Assurance Payment Status 56 71 
Controller's Office General Medical Center 7 10 
PR Accounting W-2 Form 6 9 
PR HBS Inquiry 0 17 
PR HBS Timesheet Calculations 0 2 
PR Processing and Production Direct Deposit 2 2 
PR Processing and Production Payment Details 0 1 
PR Verification of Employment How to Request VOE 1 1 
PR Verification of Employment Written VOE 2 4

My goal is to add 2 more columns to the grouped dataset:

1) A column that shows 'URT Use Count' divided by 'Number' (I want the percentage of Number that is MRN)
  2) A column that shows ResCat == 0 divided by Number (I want the percentage of Number that has ResCat equal to 0)

Here is optimally what I would want the output to look like- the two new columns are displayed below:

test URT Use Count Number Percentage_Use Same_Day_Percentage
AP Connexxus Access Request 9 9 100% 55%
AP Disbursements Payment Details 28 35 80% 77%
AP General Inquiry 1 7 14% 92%
AP General Submit Invoice for Payment 25 27 92% 97%
AP General WebNow/Invoice Copies 0 4 0% 19%
AP MyExpense Access Request 3 3 100% 50%
AP MyExpense Grant Delegated Access 0 1 0% 50%
AP MyExpense Inquiry 2 8 25% 77%
AP Quality Assurance Payment Status 56 71 79% 88%
Controller's Office General Medical Center 7 10 70% 20%
PR Accounting W-2 Form 6 9 67% 20%
PR HBS Inquiry 0 17 0% 100%
PR HBS Timesheet Calculations 0 2 0% 45%
PR Processing and Production Direct Deposit 2 2 100% 99%
PR Processing and Production Payment Details 0 1 0% 15%
PR Verification of Employment How to Request VOE 1 1 100% 12%
PR Verification of Employment Written VOE 2 4 50% 22%

Any clarification on creating these calculated fields would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Super edit, thank you. Is possible add expected output from your input data, especially new columns what need append?

Comment: Thanks @MrT for the feedback/direction - I've cleaned it up.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for the feedback/answer below - I've made the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'MRN':[4,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
                   'Number':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'ResCat':[0,1,0,0,1,1],
                   'test':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  MRN  Number  ResCat test
0  a  4.0       7       0    a
1  b  5.0       8       1    a
2  c  4.0       9       0    a
3  d  5.0       4       0    b
4  e  5.0       2       1    b
5  f  NaN       3       1    b

df1 = df.groupby("test") \
        .agg({'MRN':'count', 'Number':'size', 'ResCat':lambda x: (x == 0).sum()}) \
        .rename(columns={'MRN':'URT Use Count'}) \
        .reset_index()

print (df1)
  test  URT Use Count  Number  ResCat
0    a              3       3       2
1    b              2       3       1

df1[['a','b']] = df1[['ResCat','URT Use Count']].div(df1['Number'], axis=0)
print (df1)
  test  URT Use Count  Number  ResCat         a         b
0    a              3       3       2  0.666667  1.000000
1    b              2       3       1  0.333333  0.666667
```

Comment: Thank you so much - the solution worked and I learned more about creating calculated fields in Pandas.